# QT Hyperlink in QListView

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

Using Qt, I've created a gui that includes a `QListView` widget.

This widget is being fed data from a `QStandardItemModel` object that is made with two columns:

1. Description;
2. and Hyperlink

What I'm trying to do is to actually have the description there with a hyperlink that opens the page in the `QListView` using whatever the user's default browser is.

What I've tried so far is to actually build the Data using HTML, however this only produced the pure HTML text non-rendered.

Can anyone help?

Edited to show the code used:

Code used to build the Model:

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel;
for(int i =0; i < newsItems.size(); i++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem *> rowItems;
    rowItems.append(new QStandardItem("Description"));
    rowItems.append(new QStandardItem("http://somesite.com"));

    model->appendRow(rowItems);
}
```

Code used by a 'QPushButton' to use the model

```
//The cTicExt.getTickerNews(strTicker)  simply returns the QStandardItemModel created above
ui->listView_News->setModel(cTicExt.getTickerNews(strTicker));
```

Comment: Its Qt not QT. And please show some code.

Comment: See above, This was what I tried after I tried using a single HTML link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without model:

```
//ListWidget.h
#pragma once
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDesktopServices>

class ListWidget: public QListWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  ListWidget()
  {
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem("", this);
    addItem(item);
    QString description("Description:");
    QString hyperlinkText("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    QLabel* hyperlinkWidget = new QLabel( QString("<span>%1&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href=\"%2\">%2</a>").arg(description).arg(hyperlinkText), this);
    setItemWidget(item, hyperlinkWidget);

    connect(hyperlinkWidget, SIGNAL(linkActivated(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onHyperlinkActivated(const QString&)));
  }

private slots:
  void onHyperlinkActivated(const QString & link)
  {
    QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl(link) );
  }
};

//main.cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "ListWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  ListWidget w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
My Final solution wasnt exactly like this. But I used your slot can just called it from a double click event. 
Your post gave me the idea.